# Async/Await Multiple Functions dependent on async data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

I am creating a ReactJS app and trying to write a function that creates a set of categories.
This data is coming from an `api`.

```
const data = [
 {
   name: '',
   category = 'sports'
 },
 {
   name: '',
   category = 'food'
 },
]
```

I wrote a function that gets the data.

```
const getData = async()=>{
        const data = await fetch(url);
        // json conversion
        setData(data);
}
```

However to filter this data array, i need to pass data to another filter function. How do i do that so that my data array passes with filled value and not the initial empty array?

```
const filterData = ()=>{
        // data is global
        const categories = [new Set(data.map((item) => item.category))]
}
```

How do I call this function after my data array is ready? Or how to get the desired result.

Comment: If you want to update `categories` each time `data` changes, you can do `useEffect(() => ......., [data])`

Comment: Call `filterData` after fetching the data from api inside `getData` method.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, call the filter function after you have got the data,

```
const getData = async()=>{
    const data = await fetch(url);
    // json conversion
    setData(data);

    // Call filter from here
    filterData (data)
}
```

This is the simplest and most straightforward approach. Another way would definitely be to watch for the data change (with useEffect dependency), but that can be an overkill for a simple task IMO.

Comment: Do i have to call functions from the same function everytime i need `data` in another function??

Comment: No, since data is a global object as you said, you just need to update the global variable whenever the source data is updated (i.e. whenever you call the API maybe). I hope you have put the data in a separate service file and then sharing across components, right?